# Matching cmyk colors in plot to LaTeX

Tags: color, python, matplotlib

I'm plotting something using the Python package `matplotlib` and I'm using the `matplotlib.cm.rainbow` colormap. I need to match the same colors in my LaTeX document, but I'm having a difficult time making the colors match between what I get on my plot and what appears in my LaTeX document.

**What do I have to do to get matplotlib and LaTeX to use the same colors?** Even coming close would be a benefit.

The code I'm using to plot in `matplotlib` is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

Fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
indices = range(8)

length = len(indices)
print("\ncolors: ")
for i in range(length-1):
    left = indices[i]
    right = indices[i+1]

    c = pyplot.cm.rainbow(1.0*i/length)
    print("i={}, color={}".format(i,c))
    ax.fill_between((left,right), 0,1,
                    facecolor=c, edgecolor=c, alpha=1.00)

i +=1
left = indices[i]
right = 8
c = pyplot.cm.rainbow(1.0)
print("i={}, color={}".format(i,c))
ax.fill_between((left,right), 0,1,
                facecolor=c, edgecolor=c, alpha=1.00)
```

The output from this is:

```
colors: 
i=0, color=(0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
i=1, color=(0.24901960784313726, 0.38410574917192586, 0.98063477046897773, 1.0)
i=2, color=(0.0019607843137254832, 0.70928130760585339, 0.92328910610548931, 1.0)
i=3, color=(0.25294117647058822, 0.92563765978155632, 0.83018403081555059, 1.0)
i=4, color=(0.50392156862745097, 0.99998102734872685, 0.70492554690614728, 1.0)
i=5, color=(0.75490196078431371, 0.92090551794495368, 0.55236497296050591, 1.0)
i=6, color=(1.0, 0.70054303759329106, 0.37841105004231035, 1.0)
i=7, color=(1.0, 1.2246467991473532e-16, 6.123233995736766e-17, 1.0)
```

When I put those colors into my LaTeX table, I get the following two pages (LaTeX code follows). The first page shows the table on the left with the `matplotlib` figure on the right. The second page shows the difference between setting my `k` value between 0 and 1.

So here is my big question

**Why aren't the LaTeX colors even close to the same thing?** The first color is greenish in LaTeX and purple from `matplotlib`?!?!

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}


% Define the colors
\definecolor{colorAk}{cmyk}{0.5                   , 0.0                    , 1.0                   , 1.0}
\definecolor{colorBk}{cmyk}{0.24901960784313726   , 0.38410574917192586    , 0.98063477046897773   , 1.0}
\definecolor{colorCk}{cmyk}{0.0019607843137254832 , 0.70928130760585339    , 0.92328910610548931   , 1.0}
\definecolor{colorDk}{cmyk}{0.25294117647058822   , 0.92563765978155632    , 0.83018403081555059   , 1.0}
\definecolor{colorEk}{cmyk}{0.50392156862745097   , 0.99998102734872685    , 0.70492554690614728   , 1.0}
\definecolor{colorFk}{cmyk}{0.75490196078431371   , 0.92090551794495368    , 0.55236497296050591   , 1.0}
\definecolor{colorGk}{cmyk}{1.0                   , 0.70054303759329106    , 0.37841105004231035   , 1.0}
\definecolor{colorHk}{cmyk}{1.0                   , 1.2246467991473532e-16 , 6.123233995736766e-17 , 1.0}

\definecolor{colorA}{cmyk}{0.5                   , 0.0                    , 1.0                   , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorB}{cmyk}{0.24901960784313726   , 0.38410574917192586    , 0.98063477046897773   , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorC}{cmyk}{0.0019607843137254832 , 0.70928130760585339    , 0.92328910610548931   , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorD}{cmyk}{0.25294117647058822   , 0.92563765978155632    , 0.83018403081555059   , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorE}{cmyk}{0.50392156862745097   , 0.99998102734872685    , 0.70492554690614728   , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorF}{cmyk}{0.75490196078431371   , 0.92090551794495368    , 0.55236497296050591   , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorG}{cmyk}{1.0                   , 0.70054303759329106    , 0.37841105004231035   , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorH}{cmyk}{1.0                   , 1.2246467991473532e-16 , 6.123233995736766e-17 , 0.0}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Some funny colors}
    \begin{columns}[c]
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{lll}
                    \toprule
                    \rowcolor{colorA!25} Purple & A & 1 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorB!25} Blue   & B & 2 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorC!25} Aqua   & C & 3 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorD!25} Teal   & D & 4 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorE!25} Green  & E & 5 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorF!25} Puke   & F & 6 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorG!25} Orange & G & 7 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorH!25} Red    & H & 8 \\
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Some table with (hopefully) colorized rows}
            \end{table}
        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{colors}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}


\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Some funny colors}
    \begin{columns}[c]
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{lll}
                    \toprule
                    \rowcolor{colorAk} Purple & A & 1 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorBk} Blue   & B & 2 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorCk} Aqua   & C & 3 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorDk} Teal   & D & 4 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorEk} Green  & E & 5 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorFk} Puke   & F & 6 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorGk} Orange & G & 7 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorHk} Red    & H & 8 \\
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Some table with (hopefully) colorized rows}
            \end{table}
        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{lll}
                    \toprule
                    \rowcolor{colorA} Purple & A & 1 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorB} Blue   & B & 2 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorC} Aqua   & C & 3 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorD} Teal   & D & 4 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorE} Green  & E & 5 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorF} Puke   & F & 6 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorG} Orange & G & 7 \\
                    \rowcolor{colorH} Red    & H & 8 \\
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Some table with (hopefully) colorized rows}
            \end{table}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, the colors in the figure don't match the colors in the table and it is aggravating me why it doesn't work. Instead of the `purple, blue, aqua, ...` (I know these are not technical color names) that is seen in the figure, the colors I'm getting are `green, orange, orange red, red, gray red, violet, blue,...` The colors are not even close.

Comment: Can you instead include the tex code being produced with the table?

Comment: This does not solve the problem but I think that your `K` values in `LaTeX` `\definecolor` are `1.0` and not `0.0` and the `M` and `Y` of tthe `colorH` are `0.0`

Comment: Then as a first proof, print the color from `python` without `alpha` (or with `alpha=1`), use the generated `cmyk` code to define color in latex and compare that (without the `!25`) with the  figure.

Comment: Updated the question to hopefully make it easier to understand what is happening.

Comment: I answered your other question that was migrated from SO, as I didn't see this one. It's not really a LaTeX problem though, as you can see from my answer.